# htaccess - limit the number of words in url slug

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slug

How to limit to 4 the number of words in a slug using htaccess only?

from

```
exemple.com/hello-world-how-are-you
```

to

```
exemple.com/hello-world-how-are
```

Comment: Why not change the links?

Comment: to minimize the length of search urls produce by _GET method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a problem you need to fix in your code/database, not via `.htaccess`. It will cause a lot of extra (useless requests). A rule that would accomplish this would for example be:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+(-[^-]+){3})-.*$ /$1 [R,L]
```